# Multiple php (php-fpm) version on LNMP server

Tags: linux, nginx, php

One of the projects requires support much higher version php used in main web project

Env:
 - Debian 7.6 (3.2 x86_64)
 - Nginx 1.6.0
 - php-fpm (PHP 5.3.28)

My task: Install alternate version of php-fpm (php) and use it in another web project.
I don't want to install Apache with the desired version of php (mod-php) and use Nginx as frontend for Apache

Please describe other ways of resolving my situation, if they exist

Comment: Why don't you want to use the newest php version for all projects?

Comment: But well, here is a howto http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-use-multiple-php-versions-php-fpm-and-fastcgi-with-ispconfig-3-debian-wheezy Dunno if you use ISPConfig, but maybe it's useful.

Comment: **Charlotte Dunois**  
This suggests that programmers will transform the entire project, but there is no money. We need to run another project, with a new php, but just do not have the money to buy an additional server. This server ample power

Comment: **Charlotte Dunois**  
I don't take into account use ISPСonfig. I used to manage your system "from A to Z", without the use of third party administration utilities

Answer (score 0):

I was researching this topic in the past. Never went through with it but you might find [this](http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server) useful.